# Custom parameters in Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, android-asynctask

I'm making an offerwall SDK. First i'm initializing and getting the response. Then I have made two methods for show the offerwall. 
My query is If the developer wants anything he can add some custom parameters and get from the user. How can I add custom parameters in my Url?

my initializeSDK class is:

```
public class InitializeSDK {
/*String json = "";
URL url;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;*/

private static String PREF_NAME = "gallectica_pref_adstuck";
private static SharedPreferences prefs;

public static void init(final Context ctx, final String developer_public_key, final String offerwall_public_key) {


    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(ctx)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024) // 50 Mb
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                    //.writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
            .build();
    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefs.edit().putString("android_id", Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)).commit();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //TODO: add code to read http request and store the json data in json variable
            String json = "";
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            InputStream is = null;

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aff_id", prefs.getString("android_id", "")));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("offerwall_public_key", offerwall_public_key));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("developer_public_key", developer_public_key));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locale", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));



            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://a.nextput.com/api/init/" + developer_public_key + "/a/u");//YOUR URL  ?aff_id
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                json = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                boolean isSuccess = jObj.getBoolean("success");
                System.out.println("success : " + isSuccess);

                /* JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                   boolean state = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");*/


                return isSuccess;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("isSuccess", result).commit();

            if (result) {
                prefs.edit()
                        .putString("developer_public_key", developer_public_key)
                        .putString("offerwall_public_key", offerwall_public_key)
                        .commit();
            }
        }

    }.execute();
}

//Incent Offerwall
public static void showIncentOfferwall(final Context ctx) throws ExceptionInInitializerError {
    SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    final String offerwall_public_key = prefs.getString("offerwall_public_key", "4/9fe2d2cbaa8332a4633be17b79208181-2y-10-ELVM4HwkaYaCVu6203Zjfus-G");
    final String aff_id = prefs.getString("android_id", "");

    if (prefs.getBoolean("isSuccess", false)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, WebviewActivity_Incent.class);
        intent.putExtra("WEBVIEW_URL", "http://a.nextput.com/api/offerwall/" + offerwall_public_key + "/a/o?aff_id=" + aff_id);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        //Throw Exception
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("Please initialize first to show Incent Offerwalls.");
    }
}

//NonIncent Offerwall
public static void showNonIncentOfferwall(final Context ctx) throws ExceptionInInitializerError {
    SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    final String developer_public_key = prefs.getString("developer_public_key", "23/89533a6f4248873b08ce52ce680f29e7");
    final String aff_id = prefs.getString("android_id", "");

    if (prefs.getBoolean("isSuccess", false)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, WebviewActivity_NonIncent.class);
        intent.putExtra("WEBVIEW_URL", "http://a.nextput.com/api/offerwall/" + developer_public_key + "/a/u?aff_id=" + aff_id);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        //Throw Exception
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("Please initialize first to show NonIncent Offerwalls.");
    }
}

}
```

I have to add custom parameters in the url in below two methods showIncentOfferwall and showNonIncentOfferwall. make any string parameters. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I know what you have to do. For example your Ball.java has 3 field. You want to put an instance of Ball within params. I don't know a standard way. But you can write a method link normal toString per each object. This method much return an array of String. So you can call this method in each custom object. Making this you can retrieve params also from custom object inside custom object inside another custom object.

Ora maybe use GSON to serialize deserialize object